# Body and Section Background CSS3

Tags: css, background

Please advise what correction needs to be done to avoid body background (animated cloud) overriding the backgrounds (fixed) of individual sections.

For perspective, I'm also sharing the code in front-end builder mode, where it works perfectly fine.

Thanks.

```
<html>
<body class=" cms-index-index fullwidth cms-home">

<div class="bg-grad"><div class="clouds"><div class="cloud x1"></div></div></div>

<section class=" parallax" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/../Wallpapers.jpg'); padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px;" data-stellar-vertical-offset="20" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.6">

<section class=" " style=" padding-top:50px; padding-bottom:50px;" data-stellar-vertical-offset="20" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.6">

</section>

</body>
```

Sample Section in Front-end builder mode

```
<section class="builder-container section-builder sort-item " style="background-color: #ffffff;" data-stellar-vertical-offset="20" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.6" id="block_7">
```

CSS (for animated cloud background)

```
/*  BG Gradients
~-----------------------------------------*/
.bg-grad .parallax{
  background: #000;
  background: transparent url("http://localhost/../beauty.jpg") center 

bottom no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.bg-grad .bg-layer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 6;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.bg-grad .bg-layer.on {
  opacity: 1;
}

/*  Clouds
~-----------------------------------------*/
.cloud {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  background: transparent url('http://localhost/../clouds2.png') left 

bottom no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .cloud {
    display: none;
  }
}

.x1 {
  -moz-animation: moveclouds 40s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: moveclouds 40s linear infinite;
  animation: moveclouds 40s linear infinite;
  width: 2036px;
  height: 1608px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1400px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1400px;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
  0% {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1400px;
  }
}
```

Comment: My experimentation with styles, particularly setting position to relative, does the trick for me. Thanks for your keen interest Daniel :)

Comment: If you've found your answer, please post the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body class=" cms-index-index fullwidth cms-home">

<div class="bg-grad"><div class="clouds"><div class="cloud x1"></div></div></div>

<section class=" parallax" style="background-image: url('http://localhost/../Wallpapers.jpg'); padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px;" data-stellar-vertical-offset="20" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.6" style="position: relative;">

<section class=" " style=" padding-top:50px; padding-bottom:50px;" data-stellar-vertical-offset="20" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.6" style="position: relative;">

</section>

</body>
```